# Mysql sum and group on two tables

Tags: mysql

I'd like to sum two columns from two different tables and then group it by user ID (uid). I did fiddle but seems to multipling the results by the number of rows in a column.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/433a5e/3

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple rows for each `uid` in both table.  Hence, for a `uid`, you get a Cartesian product -- 2 rows in one table for a uid and 3 rows in the other become 6 rows with lots of duplicated data.

SO, aggregate the data before doing the join:

```
select s.uid, sumscore, sumorder
from (select s.uid, sum(s.score) as sumscore
      from scores s
      group by s.uid
     ) s left join 
     (select o.uid, sum(o.order) sumorder
      from orders o
      group by o.uid
     ) o
     on o.uid = s.uid;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/433a5e/5) are the results in a SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for this. Try this and let me know is it helpful or not for you.

```
SELECT s.uid, SUM(s.score) as score_tot, (SELECT SUM(orders.order) FROM orders WHERE orders.uid = s.uid GROUP BY orders.uid) as order_tot FROM scores as s GROUP BY s.uid
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/433a5e/18) here